# AttributeError module 'discord' has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was following a Python Discord tutorial on creating a Discord bot, when I tested it said "AttributeError type object 'Client' has no attribute 'command'" I could not find any answers.
(I tried using  `client = discord.Client()`  too)
Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
 


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        
        if message.content == ("/id"): 
            await message.channel.send(message.channel.id)

        if message.content == (".read"):
            with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
                content = f.read()
            await message.channel.send(content)

    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    @discord.command() 
    async def admins_only_command(ctx, *, args):
            if message.content == ("/apply"):
             with open("database.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(f"\n" + str(message.channel.id))
            await message.channel.send("Data stored successfully: " + str(message.channel.id))


       
        
      
            
client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert but a quick read over this [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) says the reason you are having this error is because you're trying to access an attribute that literally doesn't exist.

What you're trying to get is "discord.command()". What you need is "discord.ext.commands.command()"

change

```
@discord.command()
```

to

```
@commands.command()
```

Comment: It is not giving any errors rn, but my code under it is not working this time.

Comment: I would assume that's because async def admins_only_command(ctx, *, args): does not define "message" so "message.content" doesn't exist. @Blo

Comment: Happy to help. Hope you get your bot working.

Comment: This time it is not giving any errors, but not working. It is working without that part btw  `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    @commands.command() 
    async def admins_only_command(ctx, *, args): `